# Use golang to get RSA key the same way openssl genrsa

Tags: go, openssl, rsa

```
openssl genrsa -out $1.rsa $2
openssl rsa -in $1.rsa -pubout > $1.rsa.pub
```

I'm passing in two arguments to this tiny script, how can I do this using golang?  I'm not getting the parsing formats right.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To generate a RSA key pair and write the private and public keys to separate files, you'll need to do the following:

1. generate a RSA keypair using [rsa.GenerateKey](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/rsa/#GenerateKey)
2. get the public key component using [rsa.PrivateKey.Public](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/rsa/#PrivateKey.Public)
3. convert the keys to PKCS#1 ASN.1 DER form using [x509.MarshalPKCS1PrivateKey](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/x509/#MarshalPKCS1PrivateKey) and [x509.MarshalPKCS1PublicKey](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/x509/#MarshalPKCS1PublicKey) respectively
4. encode into PEM blocks using [pem.EncodeToMemory](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/pem/#EncodeToMemory)
5. write out to files

The full set of operations can be seen below, where `filename` and `bitSize`  are your `$1` and `$2` arguments respectively.

```golang
package main

import (
    "crypto/rand"
    "crypto/rsa"
    "crypto/x509"
    "encoding/pem"
    "io/ioutil"
)

func main() {
    filename := "key"
    bitSize := 4096

    // Generate RSA key.
    key, err := rsa.GenerateKey(rand.Reader, bitSize)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Extract public component.
    pub := key.Public()

    // Encode private key to PKCS#1 ASN.1 PEM.
    keyPEM := pem.EncodeToMemory(
        &pem.Block{
            Type:  "RSA PRIVATE KEY",
            Bytes: x509.MarshalPKCS1PrivateKey(key),
        },
    )

    // Encode public key to PKCS#1 ASN.1 PEM.
    pubPEM := pem.EncodeToMemory(
        &pem.Block{
            Type:  "RSA PUBLIC KEY",
            Bytes: x509.MarshalPKCS1PublicKey(pub.(*rsa.PublicKey)),
        },
    )

    // Write private key to file.
    if err := ioutil.WriteFile(filename+".rsa", keyPEM, 0700); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Write public key to file.
    if err := ioutil.WriteFile(filename+".rsa.pub", pubPEM, 0755); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

This will generate the two following files:

**key.rsa**:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIJJwIBAAKCAgEAsmJ+97V6zCOQdXDd0pivvgoXynKAHaImVdafXDwN+Eb2xKTg
zjhthm144DZzO9/SllCdyLwhXKBQkgim2S5A4iV5w6/yvChqL72+BrItP0+1tAgY
vt/CcShDtMdSikW13BN3+SGZSP9yrEsdU2KMK6HSGcSxMpki/XW2BbGkdr3gMtpM
...
S8tZZ/gby/k9nG7Pbw55QM8/Jkyvy/lPP94HrE+MuIiTEd9BG4c7CRNIuE6QoCjp
1+NIbqEPJTJMfH57cx8R/stLh2nBGcngjmWz+VWhufzhsOr7Wl8Xd6hf13hm4hWG
y+2pknoTGvw05tiU/eLAbNimtWMOtEdfePzT5NTjV++9kJSr470eyDs2bg==
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

**key.rsa.pub**:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
MIICCgKCAgEAsmJ+97V6zCOQdXDd0pivvgoXynKAHaImVdafXDwN+Eb2xKTgzjht
hm144DZzO9/SllCdyLwhXKBQkgim2S5A4iV5w6/yvChqL72+BrItP0+1tAgYvt/C
...
8Xil1cP/5LxIMa1WGHEG1jzrWJkyaVXHS0JOi3FcI4KPQttut2rWpSi3MtAlmuTx
k/AfM3oNnAUlcjYNa+onSs7GgLhd1A5/EiLGMR304uWKno8HrYQfESsCAwEAAQ==
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
```

I recommend you become familiar with the functions linked, their documentation is quite useful. There are also other format options available (eg: PKCS#8 and PKIX) as well as encrypted PEM for the private key.

Comment: Great answer, but for those who are trying to generate AWS CloudFront PublicKey, use `bitSize:=2048`, `x509.MarshalPKIXPublicKey` for public part and `x509.MarshalPKCS8PrivateKey` for private part.